# Default byte order of QDataStream

Tags: performance, qt, endianness, default-value, qdatastream

Default byte order of `QDataStream` is `BigEndian`, according to its documentation. AFAIK this means that written data on a little-endian platform is converted from little to big and read data is converted from big to little.

Most platforms supported by Qt, especially x86/x64, are little-endian. [This link](https://mitya57.me/weblog/2021/01/qt-big-endian-history.html) states Qt's CI doesn't even include any big-endian devices. This would mean that the default configuration of `QDataStream` requires lots of endianness conversions on Qt's major platforms - which would be pretty sub-optimal.

Did I miss something obvious? If not, why didn't Qt use `LittleEndian` as a default to support major platforms more efficiently?

Comment: Same could be argued for the network byte order (which is also BE IIRC). Presumably, they've decided to follow in their suite?

Comment: @InnocentBystander Is there something like "the network byte order"? I would have expected byte order in protocols to vary as well. What protocols do you have in mind?

Comment: The historic [IETF RFC 1700](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1700) states "*The convention in the documentation of Internet Protocols is to express numbers in decimal and to picture data in "big-endian" order*". A protocol is free to use another endianess and even a variable one but many historically used the big-endian order because of that. Big-endian benefits from being easier to debug while being a bit less efficient on little-endian architectures like the dominant x86-64 one.

Comment: @Silicomancer yes. Just google "network byte order".

Comment: Also the x86 instruction set knows has a command for this - BSWAP so even it's not optimal it's for sure not that slow.

Comment: Not to mention it can be vectorized in some case resulting in a cheap byte swap (typically using sse/avx shuffles or combine/permute instruction in neon/altivec)